# Wordpress query another wordpress database for loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been really stuck on this and on a tight deadline, basically there is two different wordpress installations. I will call the database which would be to main content: database1 and the one that the content would be loop onto: database2

Basically what I need to happen is the content from database1 to be displayed onto database2 in a loop, with metabox information, title, date, and featured image. This is how far I have gotten so far, this only shows the title and the date.

```
        <?php
        $originaldb = new wpdb('blank', 'blank', 'blank', 'blank');
        $results = $originaldb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='press' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 30" ); 
        if($results):
          foreach($results as $post): setup_postdata($post);?>

              <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                  <!-- Post Thumbnail -->


                          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>


                  <!-- /Post Thumbnail -->

                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="presslink"><a href="<?php $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'presslink', true); if($key_1_value != '') { echo $key_1_value; } ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                      <div class="pressdate"><a href="<?php $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'presslink', true); if($key_1_value != '') { echo $key_1_value; } ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date('M Y'); ?></a></div>
                  </div>

              </article>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>  
        Testing has failed
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be great, I'm not that versed in PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the post id. you can try  using

```
<?php 
$post_id=get_the_ID();
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id); ?>
```

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  query_posts('showposts'); while(have_posts()):the_posts(); the_title(); the_content(); the_post_thumbnail(); endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Try  this code hope  it will help you :

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) interface to make the two WordPress sites to communicate or to implement your own API that will export data  (the host WP), for example in json and importer on the other WP which will collect this data and return in back to desired format (two separate plugins).